# I can't figure out what is wrong with this if statement in PHP?

Tags: php, if-statement

I have built this `if statement` in PHP, but the `else` part of it is not showing any effects -

```
if($fcode=='Ok' || 'F') {
    $name = $_POST['udf1'];
    $email = $_POST['udf2'];
    $mobile = $_POST['udf3'];
    $city = $_POST['udf4'];
} else {
    $name = 'NA';
    $email = 'NA';
    $mobile = 'NA';
    $city = 'NA';
}
```

What I aim to do is, if the `fcode` variable's value is either of 'Ok' or 'F', get the POST parameters and store them into some variables (`$name`, `$email`, etc.). If it's not 'Ok' or 'F', store 'NA' into those variables.

What's happening is, the main `if`'s code is working (when the `fcode = Ok || F`) as expected, but the `else`'s code does not do anything.

Did I do anything wrong? What should I do now?

Any help is appreciated  Thanks!

Comment: I put an answer for you, your first line looks like the problem:

After your "||" logical operator, you are only putting a string in.  I assume you want to run everything in the "IF" section if $fcode returns "Ok" or "F".

Try: if($fcode=='Ok' || $fcode=='F')

Comment: Thanks @OneAdamTwelve, that worked for me 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because of your OR statement.  Try replacing the below line:

`if($fcode=='Ok' || $fcode=='F') {`

Comment: That's brilliant! That worked for me like a charm. I just forgot to add the variables name again - Thanks a lot! 